# how to get all children for tree nodes

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a domain class / table which list categories in my project as follows:

```
Category_id  |  Name    | category_parent
1            |  cat 1   | 0
11           |  cat 11  | 1
111          |  cat 111 | 11
2            |  cat 2   | 0
22           |  cat 22  | 2
```

Now I need to build a Hibernate HQL statement that will return only

```
111          |  cat 111 | 11
22           |  cat 22  | 2
```

as those are the only 2 categories with no sub-categories. I have tried the following Hibernate HQL statement:

```
select Category_id from Category where not exists ( select category_parent from Category )
```

to filter all categories that don't have their category_id listed in the category_parent field but it didn't work...so can someone please help me by telling me what exactly is wrong in my HQL and how can I modify it to achieve the result I am looking for?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Are your classes mapped properly? Your query does not look like hql. You are supposed to use class field names, not table column names. It should look more like this:

```
    select c.id from Category c where c.parent is null
```